# Infrastructure and code deployment in same pipeline or different?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, terraform, infrastructure

We are in the process of setting up a new release process in AWS. We are using terraform with Elastic Beanstalk to spin up the hardware to deploy to (although actual tools are irrelevant).

As this elastic beanstalk does not support immutable deployments in windows environments we are debating whether to have a separate pipeline to deploy our infrastructure or to run terraform on all code deployments.

The two things are likely to have different rates of churn which feels like a good reason to separate them. This would also reduce risk as there is less to deploy. But it means code could be deployed to snowflake servers and means QA and live hardware could get out of sync and therefore we would not be testing like for like.

Does anyone have experience of the two approaches and care to share which has worked better and why?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

we have both the approaches in place. The initial AWS provisioning has the last step of a null resource which runs an ansible which does the initial code deployment.

Subsequent code deployments are done with standalone jenkins+ansible jobs.